# writing into a .txt file, without renaming the first line

Tags: lua

How I can write in a file, without replacing the first line?
I tried

```
file = io.open('test123.txt', 'r+')
file:write('test')
file:close()
```

but instead of creating a new line, it rewrites the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```lua
file = io.open('test123.txt', 'r+')
file:read('L')
file:flush()
file:write('test')
file:close()
```

That keeps the first line as-is, and then starts overwriting after that. If it gets to the end, then it will start to grow the file.